# SQLalchemy: Don't execute onupdate once

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a model like

```
class Conversation(CommonBase, Base):
    [...]
    title = schema.Column(types.String(50), nullable=True)
    updated_at = schema.Column(
        types.DateTime, 
        onupdate=now)
    [...]
```

Now I need to do a data migration that should *not* change the updated_at value, but only the title. How do I do that?